# .htaccess rules not working after the PHP version change from 5.3 to 5.4 (5.5)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I change the PHP version from 5.3 to 5.4 or 5.5, rules in my `.htaccess` file are not working.

Which rules become incompatible? I am glad to any opinion, thank you!

---.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(assets/|404/|png/|js/|jpg|clearfavour)(.*)$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !/(assets/|404/|server/)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: PHP version has *nothing* to do with Apache `.htaccess` - the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Are you sure htaccess is still enabled? Due to a possible upgrade of Apache? htaccess files are disabled by default in Apache these days, due to performance issues.

Comment: Maybe the new PHP version is responsible for the scripts to fail, and therefore it *seems* as if the rewrite rules don't work.